# How Do I Remove nchar less then 10 in all column

Tags: r

I have a data frame df1. How do I remove those with character less than 10 (Print,error and no) from each column?

```
 df1 > 
  2019                 2020                  2021            
 <chr>                 <chr>                 <chr>              
1 Print                The value of x is 6   The value of x is 1
2 The value of x is 2  The value of y is 6   The value of y is 0
3 NA                   error                 The value of z is 9
4 NA                   NA                    no      


 dput(d1) >
 structure(list(`2019` = c("Print", "The value of x is 2", NA, 
 NA), `2020` = c("The value of x is 6", "The value of y is 6", 
 "error", NA), `2021` = c("The value of x is 1", "The value of y is 0", 
 "The value of z is 9", "no")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My desire output is

```
   2019                 2020                  2021          
  <chr>                 <chr>                 <chr>              
 1 The value of x is 2  The value of x is 6   The value of x is 1
 2 NA                   The value of y is 6   The value of y is 0
 3 NA                   NA                    The value of z is 9
```

enter code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> list2DF(lapply(d1, function(x) x[nchar(x) >= 10]))
                 2019                2020                2021
1 The value of x is 2 The value of x is 6 The value of x is 1
2                <NA> The value of y is 6 The value of y is 0
3                <NA>                <NA> The value of z is 9
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `across` with `summarise` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~.x[nchar(.x) >= 10]))

# `2019`              `2020`              `2021`             
#  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>              
#1 The value of x is 2 The value of x is 6 The value of x is 1
#2 NA                  The value of y is 6 The value of y is 0
#3 NA                  NA                  The value of z is 9
```

In base R :

```
data.frame(sapply(df1, function(x) x[nchar(x) >= 10]))
```